# ROS fuerte ros/package.h not found

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying out the ROS fuerte beta release, and in one of my packages the file <ros/package.h> is included, which it now refuses to find

fatal error: ros/package.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

What dependency (ros/system) do I have to add to successfully compile my program?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31209/ros-fuerte-ros/package.h-not-found/) by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) on ROS Answers with karma: 735 on 2012-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roslib contains the relevant file, though you're technically using an internal API and your code has a high chance of breaking in the future.

Also, in Fuerte, all of the include files for core libraries end up in the same hierarchy (opt/ros/fuerte/include), so almost any dependency should have given you the include path that you need.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1